# WSO2 DSS: Retrieving multiple data in JSON format

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-api-manager

Sorry new to WSO2, JSON and REST. We have DSS backend service fronted by WSO2 APIM, when I try to use a service that returns more than 1 result and specify in JSON format I'm getting this kind of results

```
employee_leave :{
  "employee_leave_id":["45","46","47","48","49","50"],
  "leave_id":["2","2","2","2","2","2"],
  "employee_id":["105","105","105","105","105","105"],
  "remarks":["test","test","test","test","test","test"],
  "approve_reject_flag":["0","0","0","0","0","0"],
  "approver_id":["","","",""],
  "approved_date":["","","","","",""],
  "created_id":["1","1","1","1","1","1"],
```

Is this correct? As the developer is complaining that multiple row results should be shown separately with the keys e.g.

```
employee_leave :{
  "employee_leave_id":[
    a: "45",
    b: "46",
    c: "47",
    d: "48",
    e: "49",
    f: "50"],
```

Where a,b,c are names/keys as requested by our developer, is the format above possible? Do I need to do something about this?

Comment: Hi Drew, Can you please elaborate your question bit more with configs details?

Comment: @Vanji, basically as I have said we WSO2 API which has an endpoint of a WSO2 DSS service. The data source is a SQL Server database. What the devs want is the JSON format above. Since APIM has an internal ESB functionality, I turned off httpcontentnegotiation and force the esb inside apim to convert the output to JSON format. Because if I turned it on, I'm getting binary results which is incorrect. The output of multiple rows shows that for each element the resulting rows are in an array form. Thay wanted that for each row there should be an equivalent key to identify each row.

Comment: @Vanji does this helps answer your question?